# Calculate the area of the crescent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I found this problem on a thread on Stack overflow where it was posted as "job interview question". Unfortunately I cannot find the question. But I saved the picture and just cannot figure it out.

The problem is to calculate the area of the crescent.

[image]

Comment: In almost any "diagram" problem about circles, putting a dot and a label at the center is helpful.  We have a label for the center of the big circle.  Put in the center of the smaller circle.

Comment: @user6312 I don't think the OP created this figure, as they indicate it was copied from another discussion.

Comment: Do you know what is amusing, I just had a candidate for an interview tell me they found the answer here.  Because I posted the [question on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/28439/7990) - didn't realise there was an answer supplied online!  Oh well, research is the name of the game for my tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming AD is the diameter of the smaller circle and C is the center of the larger circle.

If $CD = x$ then, $CE = 4+x$.

Note that angle DEA is a right triangle.

We have by the similarity of triangles EDC and ACE that

$\frac{x}{4+x} = \frac{4+x}{9+x}$

Solving gives $x = 16$. Thus the radius of larger circle is $25$. The radius of the smaller circle is $\frac{x + 9+x}{2} = 20.5$

Area of the crescent = $\pi ((25)^2 - (20.5)^2) =  204.75 \times \pi$

Comment: I don't get how CE = 4 + x, where did the 4 come from?

Comment: @shakram02: BC = CF. BC = 9 + x. CF = 5 + CE. So 5 + CE = 9 + x. So CE = 4 + x.

Comment: Nice and clever solution @Aryabhata! There's ony one thing that I didn't like: you skipped the part arriving at CE = 4 +x, maybe to make your solution look shorter. However, this kind of stuff creates confusion and this is quite inappropriate in math problem solving.

Comment: @Apostolos:  Thanks! I have no clue about the reason for skipping, though. I do vary my answer based on the context of the question. Here given that this was an interview question, I guess I was ok with leaving some steps.

Comment: Well, I don't know how interviews in math go (never had one) but I know that if you were to write this answer in highschool exam, you would get a C or D only for that, because you would have not supported your statement with proof! :)

Comment: @Apostolos: I am glad I am not in high school anymore then :-P

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you should get wiser since then! :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I'd do it:

Call $R$ the radius of the big circle and $r$ that of the small one. Now, observe that the surface of the crescent is just the difference between the surface of the big circle and the small one or

$$\pi R^2 - \pi r^2 = \pi (R-r)(R+r) \; .$$

Note how I've expressed this surface as a product of two quantities which I am now going to determine from the other data in the drawing. First the difference between the double radii is clearly 9cm:

$$2R-2r=9$$

We're halfway. Then the distance between the center of the small circle and point E is obviously $r$, but can alternatively be expressed with Pythagoras as

$$r^2 = (R-5)^2+(r-R+9)^2 \; .$$

Reordering and using what we already know about $R-r$:

$$r^2 - (R-5)^2= \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2 \; .$$

Again, using the factorizing trick

$$(r - R+5)(r+R-5)= \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2 \; .$$

Thus,

$$r+R= 5+2\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2 \; .$$

Combining everything, we get that the surface of the crescent is

$$\pi \frac{9}{2}\left(5+2\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

found the original post here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/what-is-your-favorite-whiteboard-interview-problem/28439#28439

and there is the solution in the comments:

the diameters differ by 9cm, so if the inner circle has radius r, the outer circle has radius r + 4.5. The area of the crescent is the difference in the areas of the circles: pi(r + 4.5)^2 - pi * r^2. All that's left is finding r. Define C as the point (0,0), then point E is at (0, r - 0.5) (because CE is 5cm less than the larger radius). The inner circle is shifted right 4.5cm, so its equation is (x - 4.5)^2 + y^2 = r^2. Plug in (x,y) = (0, r - 0.5) and solve for r.

Answer (score 3):

For any chord passing through a point inside a circle, the product of the lengths of the sub-segments is a number depending only on the *point*, not the chord. (This number is called the ["power" of that point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), though the value itself isn't relevant here.) That is, if any two chords contain the same point, then the products of their respective sub-segments are equal.

In your diagram ---writing $E^\prime$ for the reflection of point $E$ in the (presumed) diameter $AD$--- we have chords $AD$ and $EE^\prime$ meeting at point $P$ inside the smaller circle. Therefore,

$$CA \cdot CD = CE \cdot CE^\prime \;\;\;\; \left(\;= \text{power of point}\;\; C\;\right)$$

Now, let $R$ be the radius of the big circle. Then $CA = R$, $CD = R-9$, and $CE=CE^\prime=R-5$. By the above,

$$R(R-9)=(R-5)^2$$

so that $R = 25$. From there, it's easy.

The Power of a Point notion --which also relates not only chords, but tangents and secants that meet a point-- is a handy one to know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my brute force, minimal geometry solution.

Let the smaller circle have center $(c,0)$ and radius $r$.  Let $E$ have coordinates $(0,e)$ and $D$ have coordinates $(-d,0)$.  Let $R$ be the radius of the larger circle.

Then we have five unknowns and the five equations
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
c^2+e^2 &=& r^2 \\
c+d &=& r \\
R &=& e+5 \\
R &=& d+9 \\
R &=& c+r
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which can be easily solved.  One finds $c=4.5$, $d=16$, $e=20$, $r=20.5$, and $R=25$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,I am assuming that $O$ is the center of the inner circle.

Let,
$$CD=x$$
$$CE=y$$
$$OC=z$$
Now, from the figure we can write -
$$ 9+x=y+5 ..........(1) $$
$$ \sqrt(y^2+z^2)=x+z..........(2) $$
$$ 18-(x+z)=9+x+z...........(3) $$
solving these equations we get- 
$$x=16$$
$$y=20$$
$$z=4.5$$
so,
$$ R=x+9=16+9=25 $$
$$ r=x+z=16+4.5=20.5$$
Hence,the area of the crescent is 
$$ \Delta A =\pi R^2 - \pi r^2 =643.2410 $$