# Calculate area of a figure on the picture

Tags: geometry, area

What kind of figure is it? (the filled one). How can I calculate it's area? Known: radius of each circle and coordinates of their centers. [Picture of this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrHwn.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35898/calculate-the-area-of-the-crescent

Comment: I've just checked - no. To solve that problem, we can use for example condition, that one circle is inside another and some more. We have more common task in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure is called a [Lune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)) due to its shape resembling a crescent Moon (*Moon* in Latin is *Luna/Lune*).

For the area, if circles of radius $a$ and $b>a$ whose centers are separated by a distance $c$, the area $A$ of the lune is given by:

$$A = a^2 \left[  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{4 \Delta}\right) + \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{b-c}{a} \right) + \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{b-c}{\sqrt{(a+b-c)(a-b+c)}} \right)\right] -b^2 \left[ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{4 \Delta}\right) + \frac{\pi}{2} \right] + 2\Delta.$$

Alternatively, this is equivalent to 
$$A = 2\Delta + a^2 \sec^{-1} \left( \frac{2ac}{b^2-a^2-c^2} \right) - b^2 \sec^{-1} \left( \frac{2ac}{b^2-+a^2-c^2} \right) $$

where $\Delta = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{ (a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c) }$.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram has a discussion of the general problem of finding the area of intersection of two circles. The area of intersection can be subtracted from the area of either circle to find the area of the regions lying outside the intersection.

[Area of intersection of two general circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is to start with both circles speared area = area of smaller circle then pus the circle along the line connecting circles end when circle is fully inside other circle . area = 0. This is continuous shrinking of area and by mean value theorem hits every area in the middle. Find this equation.